# Keyboard freezes in terminal after sudo

Tags: command-line

When entering sudo commands into the terminal on a regular install (i.e. not virtualbox), the terminal asks for password, but keyboard becomes unresponsive in terminal. It is fine in other applications, so seems particular to the terminal after sudo commands.

Any ideas?

Jim.

Comment: I should note that I can type quite fine in the terminal until I come to a sudo command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK. Just type the password and press Enter. The password you enter would not be shown even in star shapes because of security issues. For example if sb watches your monitor during entering password, he/she never can find the number of characters in your password